# Presentation of calculated data within a table omitting the value of the respective column

Tags: r, flextable, gt

Apologies for the awkward title; I hope it becomes clear soon.

I have data like this: People are attributed to specific Locations, and it has been recorded whether an event has been successful or the data is missing.

```
df <- data.frame(PersonID = c(1:20),
                 Location = c("B","A","D","C","A","D","C","D","A","D","B","A","D","C","A","D","C","D","A","D"),
                 Success = c("yes","no","yes",NA,"yes","no","no","yes",NA,"yes","no","yes",NA,"yes","no","no","yes",NA,"yes","no"))
```

I would like to know how each location "performs" relative to the other locations, i. e. how many valid attempts have been successful and how the location's rate of success compares to the other locations.

So in my example, location "A" has seen 5 valid attempts (1 "NA"), of which 3 were successful (60%). The other locations have a success rate of 50%, 66.7%, and 50%, an average of 55.6%. Location A is thus 4.4 percentage points higher than the other locations' average. I want to display all that information in a table just like this:

[image: table]

I don't have a specific preference regarding packages, but I like and know some `gt` and `flextable`. Alas, not enough to implement this …

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was not trivial in any way:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
library(janitor)
library(gt)

df1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(Location) %>% 
  mutate(attempts = sum(!is.na(Success)),
         yeses = sum(Success == "yes", na.rm = TRUE),
         Success_rate = (yeses/attempts)*100) 
  
df2 <- df1 %>% 
  summarise(avgother = mean(Success_rate)) %>% 
  mutate(avgother = map_dbl(row_number(), ~mean(avgother[-.x])))
  )

df %>% 
  group_by(Location) %>% 
  summarise(attempts = sum(!is.na(Success)),
         yeses = sum(Success == "yes", na.rm = TRUE),
         Success_rate = (yeses/attempts)*100) %>% 
  bind_cols(avgother= round(df2$avgother, 1)) %>% 
  mutate(comp.avg = Success_rate - avgother) %>% 
  mutate(`attempts` = paste0("(N=", attempts, ")"),
         Success_rate = paste0(round(Success_rate, 1), "%")) %>% 
  select(-yeses) %>% 
  mutate(comp.avg = ifelse(comp.avg >0, paste0("(+",round(comp.avg, 1),")"), paste0("(",round(comp.avg,1),")"))) %>% 
  t() %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  rownames_to_column("Location") %>% 
  row_to_names(row_number = 1) %>% 
  gt()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, I am absolutely amazed by your comprehensive answer. Is there any way I can tip you?

Comment: You are welcome. The nature of helping is such that one does it gladly and expects nothing in return.

Answer (score 3):

Nice answer from @TarJae, similar approach below with flextable.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(flextable)

temp <- df |> 
  group_by(Location) |> 
  summarise(Attempts = sum(!is.na(Success)), 
            Successful = sum(ifelse(Success=="yes", 1,0), na.rm = T)) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  mutate(success_rate = round(Successful / Attempts, 3)*100) |> 
  mutate(excl.mean = (sum(success_rate) - success_rate)/(n()-1)) |> 
  mutate(comp.avg = round(success_rate - excl.mean,1)) |> 
  mutate(success_rate = paste0(formatC(signif(success_rate,digits=3),
                                digits=3,format="fg", flag="#"), "%"),
         comp.avg = ifelse(comp.avg >=0,
                           paste0("(+", comp.avg, ")"),
                           paste0("(", comp.avg, ")"))
         ) |> 
  select(-c(Successful, excl.mean)) |> 
  t() |> 
  as.data.frame()

temp <- cbind(Col1 = c("Location", "# of attempts", "Success rate", "comp. avg."),
              temp)

ft <- flextable(temp)
ft <- theme_vanilla(ft)
ft <- delete_part(ft, part = "header")
ft <- hline_top(ft)
ft <- border_inner_v(ft)
ft <- border_outer(ft)
ft
```

[image]

Comment: Also a very nice approach!.

Comment: This solution, too, is exceptional. There is only one aspect I don't fully understand. You use the `formatC()` function to display the percentages consistently, which I like! However, when the success rate is 100%, it displays `100.%` with a dot, and when the percentage is below 10, i. e. 9.5%, it displays `9.50%` instead of the desired 9.5%. I tried tinkering with `format=` and `digits=` but couldn't find success, unfortunately.

Comment: @KlausPeter  you can add a check for 100%, and change the digits to 4. Similarly, for less than 10, change digits in ```formatC()``` to 2. e.g. ```ifelse(success_rate < 100, paste0(formatC(signif(success_rate,digits=3), digits=3,format="fg", flag="#"), "%"), paste0(formatC(signif(success_rate,digits=3), digits=4,format="fg", flag="#"), "%"))```